# Twig convert_encoding drops swedish characters

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've got a database with latin1 that I want to render as utf8 with twig.

The problem is that twig's convert_encoding seems to drop swedish characters like ÅÄÖ.

According to the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html) the convert_encoding-filter uses iconv or mbstring but both of those converts my string correctly.

Example:

```
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('view');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

    echo $title . "<br>";
    echo iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', $title) . "<br>";
    echo mb_convert_encoding($title, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1') . "<br>";
    echo call_user_func($twig->getFilter('convert_encoding')->getCallable(),$title,'iso-8859-1','utf8');
```

Output:

```
before ��� ��� after
before ÅÄÖ åäö after
before ÅÄÖ åäö after
before after
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could be having issues because the wrong encoding is being provided to ICONV etc. in PHP. Have you set setlocale( LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' );? I believe by default it is set to iso.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Damn. I mixed up the order of the parameters.

It should be `convert_encoding(to, from)`. Not the other way around.

This gives the correct result:

```
echo call_user_func($twig->getFilter('convert_encoding')->getCallable(),$title,'utf8','iso-8859-1');
```